# In SQL Server unit testing project, how to make pre-test script or test script, or common script to include other script file

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I have a SQL Server unit testing project created by Visual Studio 2017, and but need to initialized many tables with many rows, I want the common scripts for Test Initialize could include external script file, so as the pre-test script.

I tried to use ":r" but failed with syntax error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got answer, the sql server unit test frame is based msunit, which does not support sqlcmd parameters. 
I have wrote a utility class to read external sql scripts.

Comment: This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/scripts-in-sql-server-unit-tests?view=sql-server-ver15 tells you about these useful `TestInitialize` scripts but gives you no idea ho to create them

Comment: To create the TestInitialize script, double click the test class. In the document that opens, look at the bar at the top. On the left pick "Common Scripts". On the right pick "Test Initialize"

Comment: Not to throw shade, but it would be more helpful if you posted an example of your utility class for others to see, rather than just mentioning that you wrote one.